# Для чего нужен тег <meta-data> в манифесте?

Tags: android

Для чего конкретно нужен тег  в манифесте?
Я понял что для каких-то дополнительных данных. Но можно поподробнее?
Желательно привести пример.

Answer (score 5):

Элемент  определяет пару "имя-значение" для элемента дополнительных произвольных данных, которыми можно снабдить родительский компонент. Составляющий элемент может содержать любое число элементов . Используют в паре имя/значение для работы с каким-то  API, например для использования сервисов Google Play, нужно прописать теги:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.company"
          android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:debuggable="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> 
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="BannerExample">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще `meta-data` используется для навигации по back stack'у активити.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ChildActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

И, например, в обработчике кнопки назад на actionbar'е (android.R.id.home):

```
if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity()); 
}
```

Так навигация будет в соответствии с рекомендациями [гугля](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте здесь: http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/10/08/using-meta-data-in-an-androidmanifest/

В частности  может быть использован для хранения данных которые могут быть необходимы каждому activity в приложении.

Это особенно полезно для таких вещей, как ключи API.

Comment: Ссылка это хорошо, но не могли бы вы добавить в примеры в ответ, чтобы он был самодостаточным, например на случай если ссылка умрет?